# Eclipse Design Studio crash after start

Tags: java, eclipse, business-objects

Installed Design Studio and Eclipse with JDK8.
Win 10, default Browser is Chrome, also tried with Edge as default.
In the Run Configuration is jre 1.8.0_133

Guideline: [GuideLine](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7979f8ee98004609ae4ae22b5e4a335d/1.6.4.0/en-US)
Downloaded Examples: [Examples](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/87a79279928f47c38bbddacf558f5d06/1.6.4.0/en-US/DS_16SP04_SDK_SAMPLES.zip)

I followed the guideline, but get stucked in 
3.1.7 Testing a Sample SDK ExtensionProcedure --> by point 3.1.7 **K** "Add SDK", because the list is empty, so can't choose anything.

When i try to run a example Project. Design Studio opening and closing right away.

I Tried with Eclipse Juno, Mars and Neon, right now iam using Mars v2.

Any Solution for that?

Eclipse console:

> !SESSION 2017-05-12 12:18:07.241
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=@qualifier@ java.version=1.8.0_131 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
>   NL=de_DE Framework arguments:  -product com.sap.ip.bi.zen Command-line
>   arguments:  -product com.sap.ip.bi.zen -data
>   C:\ds_sdk_workspace/../runtime-SDK -dev
>   file:C:/ds_sdk_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/SDK/dev.properties
>   -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2017-05-12 12:18:08.121 !MESSAGE
>   Could not bind a reference of component
>   com.sap.ip.bi.base.application.DeclaredServiceActivator. The reference
>   is: Reference[name = IActivatorBase, interface =
>   com.sap.ip.bi.base.bundle.IActivatorBase, policy = dynamic,
>   cardinality = 0..n, target = null, bind = addRICActivator, unbind =
>   removeRICActivator]
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2017-05-12 12:18:16.319
>   !MESSAGE Unable to find feature.xml in directory: C:\Program Files\SAP
>   BusinessObjects\Design Studio\features__sap.dir
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2017-05-12 12:18:16.942
>   !MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous
>   session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
>
> !ENTRY com.sap.ip.bi.zen 4 0 2017-05-12 12:18:19.451 !MESSAGE Failed
>   to create temporary folder !STACK 1
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource
>   '/com.sap.ip.bi.zen' is not open.